# What does "current" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> All divers shall be trained and **current** in CPR and diving-related first
>   aid.

What does "current" mean? I looked up a dictionary, but none of the definitions in the dictionary seem to fit in this context. Does "current" mean "be able to perform"? Or does it mean that the skills of the divers should be "up-to-date"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It either means two things:

**Current** means they should be up-to-date with their CPR skills.

Or

**Current** means that they should have a valid CPR license. For example if your  account is **current** with your mobile carrier it means that it's active and paid for. If you must be trained and **current** you must have gone through the training and gotten your CPR license certifying that you are prepared to save lives applying what you learned.

Comment: Then although the sentence doesn't mention anything about "license", the adjective "current" already implies that the person should have a valid license?

Comment: They don't make it clear in the text. I'm actually CPR licensed and to me it sounds that to be "current" means to have a valid license, because think about it. People who will apply for that position might already be trained for CPR, but their licenses might not be current, therefore current means having a valid license.

Comment: Each license has an expiration date you can only be licensed for so long. Do you get my point now?

Comment: Yes, I understood and got the point.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is poorly written. We can *assume* that *current* is referencing a license (because it normally does), but we shouldn't have to.

A much better sentence would look something like this:

> All divers shall be trained and licensed in current CPR and diving-related first aid techiniques.

(If a license isn't actually required, then *and licensed* can just be removed.)